# “heightened alert followed (or) prompted an emergency meeting”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Fill the blank with the answer

> The outbreak of swine flu that was first detected in Mexico
> was declared a global epidemic on June 11, 2009. It is the first
> worldwide epidemic designated by the World Health Organization
> in 41 years.
> The heightened alert ____ an emergency meeting with flu experts
> in Geneva that assembled after a sharp rise in cases in
> Australia, and rising numbers in Britain, Japan, Chile and
> elsewhere.
>
> A. proceeded
> B. activated
> C. followed
> D. prompted

Hello guys, the right answer is **C**, but I wonder why it can not be **D**? My understanding is

1. after a sharp rise in cases in Australia
2. "a sharp rise in cases in Australia" = alert
3. the heightened alert prompted an emergency meeting...

Why must **followed** come after the  *heightened alert*  and before the *emergency meeting*, rather than **prompted**?

Comment: Common sense (or experience) suggests that the alert (by, presumably, the Australian government) was issued after a meeting with experts. Governments do not like looking foolish, as they might if they issued alerts before meeting with experts in the relevant topics. After all, the experts might say that there is nothing to worry about, or that an alert is an over-reaction. Also alerts cost money, and governments do not like spending it if they can avoid doing so.

Comment: Michael Harvey, Thank you for explaining, I regard "sharp rise in cases in Australia" as an alert and wondering why I can not do this?@Michael Harvey

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm a native speaker and I also I assumed the right answer would have been _prompted_. I see no reason why D cannot be used.

Comment: @hexiaole - here, an 'alert' is an official government state of readiness for some kind of danger or emergency (such as disease, terror attacks, extreme weather, among other things), and would require hospitals, health authorities, broadcasters, schools, etc to carry out prepared plans or alter existing ways of working. The sharp rise in cases, after a meeting with experts, cause the government to issue the alert.

Comment: This is yet another "stupid test" for non-native Anglophones. The fact that even native speakers can disagree over the validity of the available choices is all the evidence we need for that. Effectively, the relationship between the "heightened alert" and the "emergency meeting" is just a ***judgement call*** (based on real-world knowledge and logic), which has little to do with learning the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the definitions of **alert** in Merriam-Webster:

> 1 : a state of careful watching and readiness especially for danger
> or opportunity
> 2 a : an alarm or other signal of danger
> b : an urgent notice
> 3 : the period during which an alert is in effect

Your interpretation would work with meaning 2a, where the alert is an "other signal of danger".

I believe that meaning 1 "a state of careful watching" is the correct meaning, because meaning 1 refers to a state and meaning 2a to an event. It makes sense to talk about a heightened state, but not a heightened event. Using this meaning, the sequence of events is:

1. a sharp rise in cases in Australia
2. an emergency meeting with flu experts (because they needed to discuss the sharp rise in cases)
3. a heightened alert (because the flu experts decided this)

So **followed** is the correct answer

Comment: JavaLatte, thank you for explaining, the sequence you mentioned absolute right.. But I wonder why I can not do this way:
1) after a sharp rise in cases in Australia
2) "a sharp rise in cases in Australia" = alert
3) the heightened alert prompted an emergency meeting...

Comment: That doesn't make much sense grammatically though. An alert cannot follow a meeting, _the decision to raise the alert_ might be taken following a meeting, but not the alert itself. So while I could understand something like "The alert level was raised following a meeting", I don't see how "the heightened alert", itself, could _follow_ a meeting.

Comment: @hexiaole - Chronologically your series of events *could* occur.  The statement, however, lets us know that even though chronologically possible, your series of events *did not* occur. The emergency meeting was assembled *after* a sharp rise in cases.  So we are being told *the sharp rise in cases **prompted** the emergency meeting*.  The heightened alert was subsequently ***prompted** by the emergency meeting.*

Comment: @terdon - why can't an alert follow a meeting?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am not sure if I can articulate this clearly (which doesn't lend it much credence, I know), but it feels wrong. How do you feel about "*The publication followed the meeting of the editors*"? Wouldn't you instead say something like *"The article was published after the meeting"* or similar? I would be fine with _The alert level was raised following the meeting_ but not with _The heightened alert followed_. Perhaps because it is not the alert, but its heightening that followed? I know I'm not being very clear here...

Comment: @terdon - would you have the same reservation about _the book followed the author's visit to Japan_, or _the painting followed the artist's release from an asylum_, or _the new law followed a rise in the number of murders_?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey hmm. I would, yes. Certainly for your first two examples. They bother me less than the example in the OP, but I do find them odd. This may well be some personal hangup of mine (but I am loath to accept that, of course ;) ) or it might be something like what happens with verbs which [_licence_ complements of different classes](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102038/25030). I feel like I'm clutching at straws here though since such licensing is immediately obvious to native speakers, but you clearly don't have an issue with your examples, so...

Comment: @terdon - how about this? _Twenty-five years ago, Francis Fukuyama published his book “The End of History and the Last Man” (Avon Books, 1992). The book followed his much-noted 1989 article in National Interest where Fukuyama wondered whether, as the Cold War ended, we had reached what he called the end of history._ Article in the _Chicago Catholic_

Comment: Dammit, @MichaelHarvey, that one is fine! Maybe because the previous sentence has _published_ so that makes it clearer to my pedantic self that it was the publishing of the book as opposed to the book itself which followed?

Comment: @terdon - your pedantry is misplaced. _The painting followed a period of relative lack of success for Millais_ (The Black Brunswicker by John Everett Millais, in Wikipedia). If a we say 'a book followed _some event, period, etc_' we clearly mean that some or all of the book's conception, writing, editing, proofreading, and publication followed, and a native reader sees no omission, ambiguity, or lack of clarity.

Comment: In the alphabet, B follows A. What comes first, A or B? Admittedly, I am used to hearing and reading A is followed **by** B.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that is entirely possible, wouldn't be the first time. I have posted [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/605611/25030) about this over at ELU, let's see if that helps clear things up! With my apologies to JavaLatte for hijacking the comments like this.

Comment: @terdon
@Michael Harvey
@Elliek
Thanks for you all, you enligtened me much.
The first misunderstanding is I regarded `a sharp rise in cases` as an `alert` and under the explanation of @EllieK I awared my fault. According to my misunderstanding, `The heightened alert prompted an emergency meeting with flu experts that assembled after a sharp rise in cases` will be interpreted to `A sharp rise in cases prompted an emergency meeting with flu experts that assembled after a sharp rise in cases`, that was queer.
Then, as the @MichaelHarvey said, issuing alert after meeting was a common sense.

Comment: @terdon I have added some definitions of **alert** to my answer: I hope that this clears up your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct grammatically.  But "prompted" is not correct factually.  It seems that you need to apply your factual knowledge to this situation, namely that the alert was issued after the meeting. You would have to know that the purpose of the meeting was to decide whether or not to issue the alert.

So this is a question of fact, not grammar.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You are right too.